# Writing a for loop to build a String using Streams

Tags: java

I have the following code which works. Been trying to write it in Java 8 streams to make it more readable but unable to get my head around it. Looking for any feedback to make it more readable.
Thanks.

```
// Expected output like: 1~CODE1|2~CODE2|3~CODE3|4~EX|5~CODE5
private String getFormattedValue(List<Content> list) {
    final String tilde = "~";
    final String pipe = "|";
    StringBuilder codes = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String code = list.get(i).getCode();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(code) && !"null".equals(code)) {
            code = "example".equals(code) ? "EX" : code.toUpperCase();
            codes.append(i + 1).append(tilde).append(code);
            codes.append(pipe);
        }
    }
    if (codes.toString().endsWith("|")) {
        codes.deleteCharAt(codes.length() - 1);
    }
    return codes.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you cannot consume a stream with index. You can more or less have the same result with a `IntStream` bounded to your list's size.

Then you just have map each int to a code with the same logic. And, finally, collect them (This is the only part where the Stream will shine).

```
String string = IntStream.range(0, codes.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> {
                String code = codes.get(i);
                code = "example".equals(code) ? "EX":code.toUpperCase();
                return String.format("%1$d~%2$s", i, code);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

Comment: Why add 1$ and 2$? Is it convention?

Comment: I would need to do an if check around the 3 lines inside that mapToObj. If check works but wonder if there is a way to do filter by any chance. This if check > if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(code) && !"null".equals(code))

Comment: @karvai for `1$` and `2$`, see the documentation of String.format that will point you to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax . Indeed you have to add the `if ( isNotBlank(..) && !"null".equals(..) )` I forgot it?